# Should we have a tag for Node Tools(Geometry Nodes in Tool mode)?

Tags: discussion

I think this is a distinct topic. The contexts are different and use cases as well. I think there will be questions specific to Node Tools and a tag is appropriate.

What do you think?

---

Related question:
[How to select an edge loop with geometry nodes tool mode nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304841/how-to-select-an-edge-loop-with-geometry-nodes-tool-mode-nodes)

Comment: Well, you're basically right, but ....Node Tools are Geometry Nodes. Is a separate tag really needed here? In my opinion, the topics are too close together, which is why I removed the tag again. Remember the geometry-nodes-fields tag, which was migrated to geometry-nodes. But as I said, let's hear what others think about it.

Comment: Hum not sure about it. As Quellenform mentions like *Fields*, [tag:geometry-nodes-tools] might be seen as an integral part of Geometry-Nodes in general, on the other hand, it does involve 3D View interaction, and a new set of constraints, which might be seen as new thing of its own, like [tag:simulation-nodes]. Its a bit fuzzy, I'd be inclined to include it but I don't have strong feelings either way. In the same vein we might soon need to discuss the upcoming [tag:geometry-nodes-gizmos]

Comment: The functionality is very different in terms of workflows they are used for. One is non-destructive, the other is destructive. I think people might be more interested in one than the other in some cases. For example it makes sense to filter only Node Tools questions if I want to see how people are making or attempting to make their destructive workflows more convenient if I am interested in learning more about that. In that sense I see this as very different than fields, because fields just are a part of all geometry nodes and tools are a separate type.

Comment: For example my original intention of the question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304841/how-to-select-an-edge-loop-with-geometry-nodes-tool-mode-nodes?noredirect=1#comment528584_304841 is to create a tool for everyday modelling work and I don't know, that just seems like a completely different thing than Modifier type that is about manipulating the geometry of a specific object. One is workflow improvement, the other is work to achieve a goal. Personaly I find those concepts very different.

Comment: 2¢ .. As Blender gradually heads to Everything Nodes, I, too, imagine that Geometry Nodes will need splitting into categories.. GN-Modifiers, GN-Tools, GN-Simulation, .. possibly others, for very different use-cases and implementation problems, as the system develops. As the main purpose of tags  is to reduce search-space, the criteria for me are: semantic distinction, category size.. and the size has to be anticipated, unless we can tag retrospectively.

Comment: @RobinBetts Good points. Also having an unanted tag and removing it or merging is relatively easy. Not having one and retroactively trying to tag all relevant questions is near impossible